# Search a Binary Tree And Print Children of Value

Tags: c, data-structures, recursion, binary-tree

So I have spent many sleepless nights the last two weeks trying to work on what I thought would be a simple program: I am trying to create a Binary Tree from a list of integers in a specific file. The numbers are inserted into a binary tree. I then prompt user for a value to search for to see if is a node. If it is then I print the left and right child of the searched value. I unfortunately can not for the life of me to get my code to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#define kFileName   "../../Data.txt"

struct Node {
    int           number;
    struct Node   *left, *right;
};

extern struct Node *gRootNodePtr;
void    BuildTree( void );
int     GetNumberFromFile( int *numPtr, FILE *fp );
void    InsertInTree( int num );
void    AddNode( struct Node *newNodePtr, struct Node **curNodePtrPtr );
void    SearchTree( int num, struct Node *nodePtr );
void    PrintChild( struct Node *nodePtr );

void InsertInTree(int num) {
    struct Node *nodePtr;

    nodePtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        DoError("Could not allocate memory!\n");

    nodePtr->number = num;
    nodePtr->left = NULL;
    nodePtr->right = NULL;

    AddNode(nodePtr, &gRootNodePtr);
}

void AddNode(struct Node *newNodePtr, struct Node **curNodePtrPtr) {
    if (*curNodePtrPtr == NULL)
        *curNodePtrPtr = newNodePtr;
    else if (newNodePtr->number < (*curNodePtrPtr)->number)
        AddNode(newNodePtr, &((*curNodePtrPtr)->left));
    else
        AddNode(newNodePtr, &((*curNodePtrPtr)->right));
    }

void SearchTree(int num, struct Node *nodePtr) {
    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        return;

    printf("Enter number to be searched: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    SearchTree(num, nodePtr);
    PrintChild(nodePtr->left);
    printChild(nodePtr->right);
}

void PrintChild( struct Node *nodePtr) {
    printf("%d ", nodePtr->number);
}

void BuildTree(void) {
    int     num;
    FILE    *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen( kFileName, "r")) == NULL)
        printf("Could not read numbers file!\n");

    printf("Numbers:   ");

    while (GetNumberFromFile( &num, fp )) {
        printf("%d, ", num);
        InsertInTree(num);
    }

    printf("\n-------\n");

    fclose(fp);
}

int GetNumberFromFile(int *numPtr, FILE *fp)
{
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d\n", numPtr) == EOF)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gRootNodePtr = NULL;
    int num=NULL;
    BuildTree();
    NodePtr SearchTree(num, gRootNodePtr);

return;
}
```

Comment: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: also error: conflicting types for ‘SearchTree’

Comment: is causing me not to compile. So I can't even run it. I have made many edits over the last few days and so I might have some old code in what I posted. However, I am mainly concerned with my SearchTree and PrintChild functions. As that is where I am stuck at.

Comment: `PrintChild` is spelled `printChild` the second time it is called in `SearchTree`, which won't compile. Is this the code you're trying?

Comment: Are you not using an IDE that will catch things like mispellings?

Comment: Thanks for seeing my error Martin. However, I am stuck on the init makes integer from pointer without cast.

Comment: No Falmarri, we are only allowed to use the VIM editor. *correction* it's the only thing we have access to at the school.

Comment: Some comments: you code is not complete. `DoError` is undefined. `printChild` should be `PrintChild`. In `main`: `NodePtr SearchTree` maybe `struct *Node nodePtr; ... nodePtr = SearchTree;`. Etc. Correct the errors reported by the compiler, and then ask your question here.

Comment: `int num = NULL;` NULL is a pointer type.

Comment: I'll be back. Under the advisement o khachik I am going to rewrite it a little better and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that's enough different that it isn't just giving you the answer directly, but similar enough that it might provide some help and/or inspiration. Just for grins, this demonstrates both recursive and iterative tree traversal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char *string;
} node;

node *root; /* automatically initialized to NULL */

node *make_node(char const *string) {
    node *ret = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (ret == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ret->string = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    if (ret->string == NULL) {
        free(ret);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(ret->string, string);
    ret->left = NULL;
    ret->right = NULL;
    return ret;
}

void del_node(node *node) {
    free(node->string);
    free(node);
}

int insert(const char *string, node **root) {
    if (*root == NULL)
        *root = make_node(string);
    else {
        node *iter = *root;
        for(;;) {
            int cmp = strcmp(string, iter->string);
            if ( 0 == cmp)
                /* duplicate string - ignore it. */
                return 0;
            else if (1 == cmp) {
                if (NULL == iter->right ) {
                    iter->right = make_node(string);
                    break;
                }
                else iter=iter->right;
            }
            else if ( NULL == iter->left ) {
                iter->left = make_node(string);
                break;
            }
            else
                iter = iter->left;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void print(node *root) {
    if (root->left != NULL )
        print(root->left);
    fputs(root->string, stdout);
    if ( root->right != NULL )
        print(root->right);
}

int main() {
    char line[100];

    while (fgets(line, 100, stdin))
        insert(line, &root);
    print(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for generic BST search without doing poster's homework for him.

Answer (score 0):

Go in little steps.

Create a new function `PrintLeaves`. With the needed changes, modify your `main` to

```
int main() {
    InsertInTree(42);
    PrintLeaves();
    return 0;
}
```

and tweak it until you get the 42 printed.
Then add a few more random `InsertInTree` ... and tweak ...

Answer (score 0):

The SearchTree error may stem from its usage in main(). What's NodePtr doing there? SearchTree is declared void.  Also, your integer from pointer may be due to your usage of NULL, which can be (void*)0.  Use

```
int num = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying exactly how it doesn't work, but it's pretty clear that you shouldn't prompt for the value to search for from within your recursive SearchTree routine.

Other than that, it looks like you're fairly close. Try something like this:

```
    void    SearchTree( int num, struct Node *nodePtr ) {
        if ( nodePtr == NULL )
            return;

        if (NodePtr->Number == num)
        {
           PrintChild( nodePtr->left );
           PrintChild( nodePtr->right );
        }
        else
        {
          SearchTree(num, nodePtr->left );
          SearchTree(num, nodePtr->right );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without delving into your code, here's how one usually does a search on a BST recursively:

(Pseudocode)

```
visit(node,value):
   if node is null: // empty tree
       return
   if node->key==value: // found one
       // do whatever it is you want to do with it
   if node->key<=value: // less than or equal keys are to the left 
      visit(node->left,value)
   else: // greater keys are to the right
      visit(node->right,value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your code compiled. It even does something. I tried not to touch it too much. Just to make it something , because there are no binary trees in your code and it is not clear what it is intended for. See the code below below. But before that:
1. You are not building a binary tree, you are building a linked list. Maybe, you need double-linked list of sorted numbers? If yes, the code I posted here doesn't sort it property, FYI.
2. Maybe, you are posting stack-overflow harmful code here specially, but you should care about user inputs, pointers and everything else (there were good answers from another user on this).
3. Finally, what do you want to do exactly?

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#define kFileName   "Data.txt"

struct Node {
    int         number;
    struct Node     *left, *right;
};

struct Node *gRootNodePtr;

void    BuildTree( void );
int     GetNumberFromFile( int *numPtr, FILE *fp );
void    InsertInTree( int num );
void    AddNode( struct Node *newNodePtr, struct Node **curNodePtrPtr );
void    SearchTree( int num, struct Node *nodePtr );
void    PrintChild( struct Node *nodePtr );

void    InsertInTree( int num ) {
    struct Node *nodePtr;

    nodePtr = (struct Node *) malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

    if ( nodePtr == NULL ) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory!\n" );
                return;
        }

    nodePtr->number = num;
    nodePtr->left = NULL;
    nodePtr->right = NULL;

    AddNode( nodePtr, &gRootNodePtr );
}

void    AddNode( struct Node *newNodePtr, struct Node **curNodePtrPtr ) {
if ( *curNodePtrPtr == NULL )
        *curNodePtrPtr = newNodePtr;
    else if ( newNodePtr->number < (*curNodePtrPtr)->number )
        AddNode( newNodePtr, &( (*curNodePtrPtr)->left ) );
    else
        AddNode( newNodePtr, &( (*curNodePtrPtr)->right ) );
}

void search(struct Node * nodePtr) {
        int num;
    printf("Enter number to be searched: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
        SearchTree(num, nodePtr);
}

void  SearchTree(int num, struct Node *nodePtr ) {
    if ( nodePtr == NULL )
        return;

        if(num == nodePtr->number) {
            if(nodePtr->left != NULL) PrintChild(nodePtr->left);
            PrintChild(nodePtr);
            if(nodePtr->right != NULL) PrintChild(nodePtr->right);
            printf("\n");
            return;
        } else if(num > nodePtr->number) {
            SearchTree(num, nodePtr->right);
        } else {
            SearchTree(num, nodePtr->left);
        }
}

void    PrintChild( struct Node *nodePtr ) {
    printf( "%d ", nodePtr->number );
}

void    BuildTree( void )
{
    int     num;
    FILE    *fp;

    if ( ( fp = fopen( "Data.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL )
        printf( "Could not read numbers file!\n" );

    printf( "Numbers:   " );

    while ( GetNumberFromFile( &num, fp ) )
    {
        printf( "%d, ", num );
        InsertInTree( num );
    }

    printf( "\n-------\n" );

    fclose( fp );
}

int GetNumberFromFile( int *numPtr, FILE *fp )
{
    if ( fscanf( fp, "%d\n", numPtr ) == EOF )
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gRootNodePtr = NULL;
    BuildTree();
        search(gRootNodePtr);
        return;
}
```

Comment: wow, I am overwhelmed with the all the great responses. As far as I want to do, is just have the program prompt me for a number. If number doesn't exist then printf("Sorry. Number doesn't Exit.") **Note, I originally had written a function for DoError that would replicate the printf but as a system message I have since scratched that idea until i could get the program working. But If the value was found then it would print the value of the left child and print the value of the right child.

Comment: So you need double linked list, and not a binary tree.

Comment: well, we were asked to insert the data.txt file into a tree, then using preorder traversal find the left and right child of the value that we are searching for. I put the code into and made a couple of adjustments. And it is working. However, I just need to make a few more changes and I think I see some of my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

`This is my code for binary tree and all of its` operations in php:

```
<?php
```

class Node
{
 public $data;
 public $leftChild;
 public $rightChild;

public function __construct($data)
  {
   $this->data=$data;
   $this->leftChild=null;
   $this->rightChild=null;
  }
 public function disp_data()
  {
   echo $this->data;
  }

}//end class Node
class BinaryTree
{
 public $root;
 //public $s;
 public function __construct()
  {
   $this->root=null;
   //$this->s=file_get_contents('store');

}
//function to display the tree
  public function display()
  {
   $this->display_tree($this->root);

}
  public function display_tree($local_root)
  {

if($local_root==null) 
     return;
    $this->display_tree($local_root->leftChild);
    echo $local_root->data."
";
    $this->display_tree($local_root->rightChild);

} 
// function to insert a new node
  public function insert($key)
   {
    $newnode=new Node($key);
      if($this->root==null)
        {
         $this->root=$newnode;
         return;
        }
      else
        {
         $parent=$this->root;
         $current=$this->root;
           while(true)
             {
               $parent=$current;
                 //$this->find_order($key,$current->data);
                if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
                  {
                      $current=$current->leftChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->leftChild=$newnode;
                          return;
                         }//end if2
                  }//end if1 
                else
                  {
                      $current=$current->rightChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->rightChild=$newnode;
                          return;
                         } //end if1
                  } //end else
             }//end while loop 
        }//end else

} //end insert function

//function to search a particular Node
 public function find($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
            if($key==$this->find_order($key,$current->data))
              {
                $current=$current->leftChild;
              }
            else
              {
                $current=$current->rightChild;
              }
            if($current==null)
              return(null);

```
      }
     return($current->data);
```

}// end the function to search
 public function delete1($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
    $parent=$this->root;

```
$isLeftChild=true;
 while($current->data!=$key)
      {
       $parent=$current;
       if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
         {
          $current=$current->leftChild;
          $isLeftChild=true;
         }   
       else
         {
          $current=$current->rightChild;
          $isLeftChild=false;   
         } 
        if($current==null)
          return(null);
      }//end while loop 

  echo "<br/><br/>Node to delete:".$current->data;
 //to delete a leaf node 
 if($current->leftChild==null&&$current->rightChild==null)
   {
       if($current==$this->root)
          $this->root=null;  
      else if($isLeftChild==true)
       {
        $parent->leftChild=null;
       }  
     else
       {
        $parent->rightChild=null;
       }
     return($current);       
   }//end if1
 //to delete a node having a leftChild
```

else if($current->rightChild==null)
       {
          if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->leftChild;
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
           }
          else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->leftChild;
           }
          return($current);
       }//end else if1
    //to delete a node having a rightChild
   else if($current->leftChild==null)
       {
         if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->rightChild;
         else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->rightChild;
           }
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->rightChild; 
           }
           return($current);
       }
   //to delete a node having both childs
    else
       {
        $successor=$this->get_successor($current);
        if($current==$this->root)
          {
            $this->root=$successor;

```
      }
    else if($isLeftChild==true)
      {
       $parent->leftChild=$successor;
      }
    else
      {
       $parent->rightChild=$successor;
      }     
     $successor->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
    return($current);
   }
```

}//end the function to delete a node
//Function to find the successor node
 public function get_successor($delNode)
  {
   $succParent=$delNode;
   $successor=$delNode;
   $temp=$delNode->rightChild;
    while($temp!=null)
         {
          $succParent=$successor;
          $successor=$temp;
          $temp=$temp->leftChild;
         }
   if($successor!=$delNode->rightChild)
     {
      $succParent->leftChild=$successor->rightChild;
      $successor->rightChild=$delNode->rightChild;
     }
  return($successor);
  }
//function to find the order of two strings
 public function find_order($str1,$str2)
  {
     $str1=strtolower($str1);
     $str2=strtolower($str2);
     $i=0;
     $j=0;

```
 $p1=$str1[i];
 $p2=$str2[j];
```

while(true)
   {
       if(ord($p1)

```
       return($str1);
     }
  else
     {
       if(ord($p1)==ord($p2))
         {
          $p1=$str1[++$i];
          $p2=$str2[++$j];
          continue;
         }
      return($str2); 
     }
```

}//end while

} //end function find string order

public function is_empty()
  {
    if($this->root==null)
      return(true);
    else
      return(false);
  }
}//end class BinaryTree
?>